# Two tags for controls. Why not merge them?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

At the moment, [Signal Processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com) has the tags [control-systems](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-systems) and [control](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control). Why not [merge](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31/21075) them?

---

**Related**

- [Where do PID loop + other control systems questions go?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/143/21075)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DONE! Thank-you for pointing it out.

[image: Screenshot of output of merging the two tags.]